# In native C++, how does one use a SqlCe .sdf database?

Tags: c++, database, sql-server-ce

Is there a simple way, without .NET?

I've found some libraries but none for SqlCe 3.5. There is http://sqlcehelper.codeplex.com/ but it's far from done, since a major feature like using a password is not yet implemented. I've looked at the source and it uses OLEdb to handle the database.

The official Microsoft Northwind example (that is shipped with SQL Compact 3.1, but not with 3.5) also doesn't work, I've tried setting it up with no success.

Actually I don't have a sample working code. Was anyone able to set it up paired with a passworded .sdf?
What are the alternatives?
Thanks.

Comment: Does this help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174516.aspx ?

Comment: There is no way in native C++, you'll have to use an external library.

Comment: I recently posted C++ source code for accessing SQL Server Compact 3.5 databases under <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8780656/raw-c-code-to-display-the-names-of-tables-in-an-sql-compact-server-using-ole-d/9107697#9107697">Raw C++ code to display the names of tables in an SQL compact server using OLE DB</a>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several months ago, I compared certain database implementations for our desktop application. Using SqlCE with native C++ code is awful. If I remember right, some of native examples contains "goto" type jumps, hard to bind data and so on. If you have a choice then use SQLite.

Comment: Hello,
sorry for this, I dropped out from that project, but was still there to implement the SQLite database and it was working great. We had some serious stress and HW fault tests and it was really superb.
I reckon it is not good to leave a question unanswered, so I'll tag your post as the answer... :)